# LDAP ADSDSOObject with OPENROWSET multiple conditions

Tags: sql-server, ldap, openrowset

All I have been banging my head on this for hours, time to ask for help.

Does anyone know how to query LDAP ADSDSOObject with OPENROWSET when using multiple conditions?
I have been trying and I keep getting an error.  The issue is with the `()` Parentheses. Can someone show me how to work around this? Thanks!

```
SELECT  TOP 901
            [USN]                 =  CONVERT(BIGINT       ,usnCreated)
         ,  [Name]                =  CONVERT(VARCHAR(500) ,name)
         ,  [Groups]              =  CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX) ,distinguishedName)
         ,  [System_Flags]        =  CONVERT(BIGINT       ,systemFlags)
         ,  [Group_Created_Date]  =  whenCreated
         ,  [Group_Last_Modified] =  whenChanged
   FROM OPENROWSET('ADSDSOObject','source'; 'UserName'; 'Password', '

  SELECT  name
       ,  distinguishedName
       ,  usnCreated
       ,  systemFlags
       ,  whenChanged
       ,  whenCreated
    FROM  ''LDAP://DC=one,DC=two''
   WHERE  (   objectClass  = ''group''
          OR  objectClass  = ''groupofnames'' 
          OR  objectClass  = ''groupofuniquenames''
          )
     AND  whenChanged > ''19000101000000.0Z''
ORDER BY  usnCreated

')
```

Answer (score 0):

OLE DB query is not SQL.  It's SQL Dialect.
Please ref: [SQL Dialect](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-tw/windows/win32/adsi/sql-dialect)

```sql
SELECT  TOP 901
            [USN]                 =  CONVERT(BIGINT       ,usnCreated)
         ,  [Name]                =  CONVERT(VARCHAR(500) ,name)
         ,  [Groups]              =  CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX) ,distinguishedName)
         ,  [System_Flags]        =  CONVERT(BIGINT       ,systemFlags)
         ,  [Group_Created_Date]  =  whenCreated
         ,  [Group_Last_Modified] =  whenChanged
   FROM OPENROWSET('ADSDSOObject','source'; 'UserName'; 'Password', '
  SELECT  name
       ,  distinguishedName
       ,  usnCreated
       ,  systemFlags
       ,  whenChanged
       ,  whenCreated
    FROM  ''LDAP://your ldap...''
   WHERE objectClass  = ''group''
    or objectClass  = ''groupofnames'' 
          OR  objectClass  = ''groupofuniquenames''
')
Where whenChanged > '1900-01-01'
ORDER BY  usnCreated
```

Comment: My issue is not with the whenChanged time or the format that the time is in. When querying LDAP if the Where is complex you have to use Search Filter Syntax ( https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/adsi/search-filter-syntax?redirectedfrom=MSDN) I just don't know how.

There is also something here (https://pawlowski.cz/2011/04/12/querying-active-directory-sql-server-t-sql/)

Comment: Additionally there is a max number of rows that can be selected when querying LDAP Hence the top 901, by changing the order by location and time the entire query doesn't complete as it attempts to return too many rows.